# how to print range of numbers by using passing value to variable from 1 to $num with echo command?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

I want to print all the integer value from 1 to 10 by using `echo {1..$num}` and i want to used it pdftk

If i do with `echo {1..10}` it is printing what i exactly want, but i want to pass a value to some variable and that variable below is my MWE.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  num=10
  echo {1..10} # This code printing correctly
  echo {1..$num} # This code not printing correctly
  pdftk {1..$num}.pdf cat output final.pdf
```

but it is prininting 1..10 only but i want to print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion is performed before parameter expansion. Therefore your approach does not work. You could do instead a

```
num=10
seq $num
for n in $(seq $num)
do
  pdftk $n.pdf
done
```

If you want to avoid a loop, do instead a

```
pdftk $(seq $num | sed 's/$/.pdf/')
```

or

```
pdftk $(printf "%s.pdf " $(seq $num))
```

instead.